# Can I travel to Cyprus with German temporary residence permit?

Tags: visas, air-travel, permits, cyprus, eurozone

Currently, I have temporary German residence permit its called "Vorläufige Bescheinigung über einen bewilligten Aufenthaltstitel" as I understood right it's the same as Fiktionsbescheinigungen just a new standard. But I really cannot find any information about travelling with this document.
Additional info:

1. My Schengen Visa is already expired.
2. Originally I am from Russia.
3. Cyprus is not Schengen zone but it's in Eurozone.
4. Going to travel to the south part of Cyprus (this info may be useful since there are conflicts with the north part).

Comment: What you have is not a Fiktionsbescheinigung. A Fiktionsbescheinigung (fictional certificate) is issued if a foreigner is allowed to stay in Germany during the processing of a residence permit application. What you have is a preliminary confirmation that your application has been approved. It is usually issued if there is a backlog in the production of the actual residence permit card and it will take some time for you to get the 'real' document.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo hm, thanks for the explanation! So does it mean that I already can travel in Eurozone without restrictions?

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with the Euro zone, which is a monetary union and not at all related to immigration requirements. You are allowed to travel to Cyprus, because Cyprus allows holders of a German residence permit (actually residence permits from most EEA countries) to enter without a visa. I am however not sure if your preliminary paper is recognized by Cypriotic authorities as a proof of a German residence permit. I did therefore not write a proper answer and I am not sure if you in practice are able to travel to Cyprus with the paper you currently have.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Thanks for these details! I am going to contact Cyprus embassy with my concerns, maybe they already had such situation before

Answer (score 3):

That very much depends on how long your title is valid. If you check [Visa-Express](http://www.visa-express.de/deutsch/land.php?ISO3166=CY), it says:

> Alle nicht deutschen Staatsangehörigen (ausnahme Türkei), die eine mindestens 3 Monate gültige Aufenthaltserlaubnis für Europa besitzen, benötigen kein Visum.

Meaning: All non German citizens (except Turkey) holding a residence permit for Europe valid for at least 3 month, do not need a visa.

Knowing first hand: a Russian passport combined with a permanent residence permit for Germany is accepted without any trouble.